# Initialize C struct by return value of a function

Tags: c, structure

I am trying to make a function to initialize a structure and pass it back in its return value, but I cannot make it work. Where did I make a mistake? I get a segmentation fault error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int id;
    char *name;
} Object;

Object object_ctor(int id, char *name);

int main()
{
    Object x;

    x = object_ctor(1, "Alex");

    printf("%s\n", x.name);
    return 0;
}

Object object_ctor(int id, char *name)
{
    Object y;
    y.id = id;
    y.name = *name;

    return y;
}
```

Comment: Y is local to stack .  Gone when function exits.  Need to use heap

Comment: You're de-referencing the name un the `object_ctor`. Don't do that. Although you may want to use `strdup(name)` or similar so you have a heap-allocated version of the string because if you call the `object_ctor` from a different function, the pointer may possibly point to a string that was allocated on the stack (i.e. no longer exists).

Comment: @OldProgrammer: It is perfectly permissible to return a (copy of) a local variable such a structure.  What is not permissible is returning a pointer to a local variable.  If the function returned an `Object *`, then your concern would be legitimate.

Answer (score 2):

> Where did I make a mistake?

This is the line:

```
y.name = *name;
```

It is wrong for couple of reasons.

1. You are assigning a `char`, `*name`, to a variable of type `char*`, `y.name`. It violates the constraints of the assignment operator for pointers.

   From the C11 standard:

   > **6.5.16.1 Simple assignment**
   >
   > **Constraints**
   >
   > 1 One of the following shall hold:
   >
   > ...
   >
   > — the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;
   >
   > — the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) one operand is a pointer to an object type, and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of `void`, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;
   >
   > — the left operand is an atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer, and the right is a null pointer constant; or

   The RHS of that assignment does not satisfy any of the above constraints.
2. When you treat that value as a null terminated string in

   ```
   printf("%s\n", x.name);
   ```

   you run into undefined behavior.

You can detect errors like this by turning up the warning level on your compiler. I get the following waring when compiling with `gcc -Wall`.

```
soc.c: In function ‘object_ctor’:
soc.c:26:12: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     y.name = *name;
            ^
```

You need to use something like:

```
y.name = strdup(name);
```

If `strdup` is not available on your platform, it's not too hard to implement. You can find an implementation easily on the web also.

Comment: Note that `strdup()` does typically use `malloc()` which means you need to free it. Perhaps an `object_dtor` function can `free()` the memory allocated from `strdup()`.

Comment: I also tried this:y.name = name; and it worked, how is that possible?

Comment: @Zeusko, it works because of the special ways compilers treat string literals. In this case, `y.name` points to the string literal`"Alex"`. One needs to be careful when dealing with string literals. You can read about it on SO and elsewhere on the web.

Comment: `y.name = *name;` is a constraint violation, so the whole program is undefined.  Your answer reads as if the line is OK but no UB until later on.

Comment: @M.M, please elaborate. As per understanding, an integer may be converted to any pointer type.

Comment: @RSahu a cast is required. See C11 6.5.16.1/1